# Spring 5 Reactor - Emitting item every 1 second

Tags: spring, kotlin, rx-java, reactor

I am trying to emit value every second as

```
Flux.just(User("A"), User("B"), User("C")).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

but it is emitting everything at once with starting delay of 1 second. How can I introduce the delay for each element emitting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flux.just(User("A"), User("B"), User("C"))` is just one collection of items, you probably want something like

```
Flux.fromIterable(listOf(User("A"), User("B"), User("C"))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```